# How to install eslint-airbnb?

Tags: npm, eslint

when i run 
`(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)` successfully. `eslint --init` and run the script in `package.json`.

Info : my Node `node v7.5.0` `npm 4.1.2`

there is problem below.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/next/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node"
/Users/next/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! beslint@1.0.0 lint: `eslint app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the beslint@1.0.0 lint script 'eslint app.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the beslint package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     eslint app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs beslint
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls beslint
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/next/es6/jsmodules/beslint/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure that running `eslint --init` worked ?

This is like you have no `.eslintrc` file (the configuration file for ESLint parser options and rules). Check/create the `.eslintrc`file at the root directory of your project that you called "*beslint*".

Then you'll need to add this in the `.eslintrc`file in order that ESLint take into account that you want to extend the rules from the Airbnb team:

`{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}`

Note that you can install different rules from the Airbnb team:

- "*airbnb*": Airbnb ESLint rules, including ECMAScript 6+ and React
- "*airbnb-base*": Airbnb ESLint rules, including ECMAScript 6+
- "*airbnb-base/legacy*": Airbnb ESLint rules, including ECMAScript 5 and below

The `extends` value in your `.eslintrc` file should match your installation and be one of these three previous values.

I made a little command line tool that can install ESLint with one of these three different Airbnb configs. It automatically creates and configure the `.eslintrc` file if it has not already been done. It helps me a lot on my personal projects and at work! It's called [esbnb](https://github.com/adrienvalcke/esbnb). Hope it could help you.